# Специфичная сортировка чисел по возрастанию/убыванию внутри массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, фильтрация

Нужно произвольный массив чисел отфильтровать на чётные/нечётные, затем чётные отсортировать по возрастанию, а нечётные - по убыванию. И всё это нужно сделать без создания новых массивов в процессе фильтрования/сортировки, внутри, единственного имеющегося, массива. Я представляю данную сортировку только созданием новых массивов с использованием методов .filter() и .sort() и т.д. Как это реализовать только внутри данного массива? Буду премного благодарен.

Допустим этот массив:

```
let numArray = [2, 7, 8, 9, 3, 10, 4, 5, 6, 1];
```

Comment: что именно не понятно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let numArray = [2, 7, 8, 9, 3, 10, 4, 5, 6, 1];
numArray.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a % 2) {
    return b % 2 ? b - a : 1;
  }
  return b % 2 ? -1 : a - b
})
console.log(numArray)
```